# Localhost:3000 is not working properly in windows while creating a reactjs app with CRA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, vue.js, localhost

There are few points, for the past few days I am trying to figure out the issue but I am stuck.

1. I have tried to stop localhost:3000 with

   netstat -ano | findstr :3000
   taskkill /PID myPIDhere /F

But still, then I am getting-

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5748
```

and it says - ERROR: The process with PID 5748 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.

2. And still, when I visit localhost:3000 it trying to load again and again.
3. whenever I try to create a reactjs app with CRA.. the terminal hangs there forever.
4. same goes for NPM install in a creatjs app.

Comment: did you tried `reboot`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 2 : `netstat -ano | findstr :3000
        tskill typeyourPIDhere`

Use `tskill` in windows cmd vs `taskkill` on git-bash

EDIT: Try `wmic process where name="[process name]" call terminate / delete`

Off the top of my head, try changing CRA port to something else?

https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/reactjs-change-port-number.html

Try one of these methods, and see if they help you at least run CRA.

Comment: trying it out now

Comment: Weird things I have read is to restart your PC! I'm sure you would have tried that. Shut down wait and power back on. But that's no logical solution.

Comment: Both changing the port and the `wmic` terminate / delete process?

Comment: Don't know if you get notified for Edits
`netstat -ano | findstr :3000` Followed by `tskill typeyourPIDhere` in the Windows Command Prompt not in Git-Bash